# Is there a way to get more in depth stack traces from react native that point to actual files?

Tags: react-native

I've found that the stack traces for react native are very mysterious. They often don't actually point to files I've created but to weird react native files that are of zero help to me in tracking down a bug.

For example, I have an image somewhere on my home screen that must be temporarily null before being set and it's throwing this warning:

[image]

This is IMO not a good warning. I have a lot of images on my home screen. This error might as well say "something went wrong somewhere".

How can I make it more clear what file is generating this warning?